# How to get a value from a div tag using cheerio's nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm making a webscraper using `cheerio` and `request` in NodeJS and I can't get a special value from a `div`.

I would get the 'idproduit' value (223) from this `div` :

```
<div class="vignette_footer js-vignette_footer" idproduit="223">
```

For this I'm doing : (EDITED)

```
$('.vignettes_produit li').each(function(i, element) {

        var jsObject = { id: id++, idProduit: null};

        jsObject.idProduit = $(this).find('.vignette_footer).attr('idproduit');
});
```

But it's gaving me an `undefined` result.

Does anyone know how I have to do ?

Comment: What's `this` in the context of your code?

Comment: This in the context of my code is the class over which I'm looping @dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Following your edit, changing `$('.vignettes_produit li')` to `$('li[class="vignettes_produit"]')` should solve your issue. For example:

```
let cheerio = require('cheerio')

let $ = cheerio.load('<ul><li class="vignettes_produit"><div class="vignette_footer js-vignette_footer" idproduit="223">1</div></li><li class="vignettes_produit"><div class="vignette_footer js-vignette_footer" idproduit="345">2</div></li><li class="vignettes_produit"><div class="vignette_footer js-vignette_footer" idproduit="456">3</div></li></ul>')

$('li[class="vignettes_produit"]').each(function(i, element) {
    console.log($(this).find('.vignette_footer').attr('idproduit'))
})
```

Comment: Thanks @dan for your answer. Unfortunately the idproduit value change for each div and I'm looping on this div s. I'm also loading all the body at the begining.

Comment: No problem. Would you mind updating your answer with the code your using to look through the divs and I'll take another look?

Comment: So have I, hopefully that helps.